# With Python, how can I get a bunch of url that follow a specific format?

Tags: python

I'd like to get all usernames/userids for registered users on a social network, but have no idea how to start with...

I've noticed that all personal webpages follow the same format:
http://www.examplewebsite/user/***

examplewebsite: I made it up, it could be facebook or twitter

***:  is the username of that user

So, I'm wondering if I could that let python code automatically search and return all the url (just the address, web content is not needed) that satisify the format. What python func/library should I use?

Thank you all!!!

Comment: What have you tried yourself? This is a place for asking questions about your code, not to have people write it for you.

Comment: Thank you Elias. So far I've tried to use the websit's API to get all user info. But the API only works when you specify a username or userid. So I let user_id(numbers) in a range and do a for loop, hoping to scan all users. Then the problem came: if a person user a number(e.g.,1234) as his username, then you'll get the result of the person with username 1234, and you'll never get the person whose user_id is 1234. That's why I'm bothered.

Comment: Put this in your question then! That's useful information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with a site that returns 404 when an invalid username is provided, and using the http.client (httplib in python 2.x) library:

```
try:
    connection = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.examplewebsite.nnn")
    connection.request("HEAD", "user/" + user_id)
    print(connection.getresponse().status)
except Exception as ex:
    print("oops! " + str(ex))
```

If you get 404, or another error code, it's not a real page. This is assuming, though, that they don't have a redirect page to handle 404, or some sort of default rerouting.

I'm assuming there's some sort of alphanumeric pattern you're talking about, so if you were looking for just numbers, you could just do for user_id in range(10000, 100000).

Note that any sensibly-designed website is probably going to catch onto what you're doing (essentially crawling their site) and lock you out somehow.

If you wanted to try all alphanumeric permutations, you could use itertools.permutations, where perm_len is the length of the string returned:

```
for perm_len in range(min_username_len, exclusive_max_username_length):
    perms = itertools.permutations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890', perm_len)
```

Note that what you're doing at this point is basically trying to brute force whatever social network you're after, and that's going to be incredibly, deeply inefficient. Again, you'll probably get locked out easily.

Which is secondary to the problem you have that the response code isn't necessarily going to tell you anything. For example, Facebook returns 302 for all usernames, not just valid ones. I think you're making too much of being able to see the basic URL structure of the website.

Lastly, what you're doing may not even be legal in your jurisdiction. Tread lightly.

Comment: Thank you furkle. But the trouble is username is actually alphabetic...What could I do in this case?

Comment: @ShunyuanZhang I've updated it. You're going to have a lot less luck in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll learn what you've posted (I didn't use httplib before, and will have a practice). And I really appreciate your kind words and suggestions. Have a great weekend:)

Comment: @ShunyuanZhang Thanks! Please don't forget to check the answer as your selected answer.